# Ping: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: 22.04, ping

My first day of using Ubuntu 22.04 caused my manager asked me to. After configuring the network to static IP, I'm struggling to find out why it could not ping servers using their hostnames, but IP is fine.

[image]

```
root@lnxuserver:/etc/netplan# cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml
#This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.xx.xx.50/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.xx.xx.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [10.xx.xx.xx, 10.xx.xx.11]
```

Comment: Did you configure a DNS server with your static address?

Comment: Probably because you didn't configure DNS correctly. If you want better answer than that, you have to include more information about your setup.

Comment: Please see my network config:

root@lnxuserver:/etc/netplan# cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.xx.xx.50/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.xx.xx1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [10.xx.xx.xx, 10.xx.xx.11]

Comment: Please don't put relevant information in a comment. Edit your question and paste the `yml` file into it. Especially `yml` files are completely unreadable in a comment.

Comment: thanks, I have modified my question and pasted by yml.